# Exchange Web Services- Update tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

```
Dim clientTZService As ExchangeService = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)


clientTZService.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userEmail, userPass)
clientTZService.AutodiscoverUrl(userEmail, AddressOf RedirectionCallBack)


      Dim Task1 As Task = New Task(clientTZService)
      Task1.Subject = "New Task"
      Task1.Body = New MessageBody(String.Format("test"))
      Task1.StartDate = DateTime.Now
      Dim DueDate As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,      DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + 2)
      Task1.DueDate = DueDate
          Task1.Recurrence = New Recurrence.MonthlyPattern(New DateTime(2017, 4, 11, 10, 0, 0), 1, 11)
          Task1.Recurrence.StartDate = New DateTime(2017, 4, 11, 10, 0, 0)
          Task1.Save(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, "test@domain.com"))
```

Can anyone let me know the simplest way to update tasks using EWS with an Eg:
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a painstaking research I think I have found a way to do this.This updates the task to completed!

Please see below:

```
  Dim instance As ConflictResolutionMode =  ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite


            Dim tasksFolder As Folder = Folder.Bind(clientTZService, New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, useremail))

            tasksFolder.Load()
            For Each task1 As Task In tasksFolder.FindItems(New ItemView(100))
                task1.Load()
                If task1.Id.ToString = taskrow("OutlookTaskID") Then
                    task1.PercentComplete = 100
                    task1.Update(instance)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The Task Class which you used to create the Task has an Update method https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task.update(v=exchg.80).aspx which is what you would use to update a Task. Like any other Mailbox Item in EWS before you can update it you need to use FindItems https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633693(v=exchg.80).aspx to find the EWSId of the object you want to update and then change the property you want to change and call the Update method.

Comment: I'm saving the ID of the task after it is created.So I want to know if there is any way of lloping through the tasks folder and then edit the task when the client wants to change or amend it?

Comment: Will something like this work?  After saving the task I'm getting the ID if the task using TAsk1.ID and then saving it to database.  When I want to update it,                    `code`    Dim item As ItemId = taskrow("OutlookTaskID")
                
           
                    Dim task As Task = task.Bind(clientTZService, item)
                    task.Load()
                   task.PercentComplete = 100
                   Dim instance As ConflictResolutionMode = 
                 ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite
                      task.Update(instance)